# pushd throws access denied when trying to access windows 10 from jenkins job which is in windows 7 professional

Tags: jenkins, soap, pushd

I want to execute some SOAP suites which is located in a Windows 10 machine.
But I have my jenkins setup and job everything in a Windows 7 machine.

When I tried to execute the below Windows batch command:
**c:
pushd \xyzsoapmachine01\c$
cd Program Files\SmartBear\ReadyAPI-2.5.0\bin
testrunner.bat -s "Automation Suite" -c "TestCase_JenkinsCheck" Z:\Projects\xyzsoapui-project.xml
popd**

I get the error as pushd \xyzsoapmachine01\c$
Access is denied.

how to resolve this please?

Comment: Is `\xyzsoapmachine01\c$` a valid directory on your Windows machine?

Comment: xyzsoapmachine01 - machine name and c is the directory